# Git Extensions: How to set the URL using a global variable

Tags: windows, global-variables, git-extensions

I am wondering: is there a possibility to state the URL of a remote repository with a variable from the system using Git Extensions.

So I declared a global variable in windows: `CENTRAL_REPO`
and stored the path to my central repository there.

Usually I would now write something like this
`%CENTRAL_REPO%\source`
to get to the place I have my Repo at. Sadly, all the possibilities I know do not work and I have no idea where to look at. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have now read a lot and also studied the Git Extensions manual for some time. I have tried basically all available combinations like `[Central_Repo]\source` or `$(CENTRAL_REPO)\source`. **It seems like there is no way to use a windows global variable or any other variable to state the URL of a Repository**.

In case anyone got a different answer later on, I am happy to hear it!